# action of the extra-special group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, groups-of-lie-type

I'm reading a paper which has this line:

A direct computation shows that P$\Omega_8$($\mathbb K$) has an elementary abelian subgroup $X = 2^2$ such that $C_{P\Omega_8$(\mathbb K)}(X) = T_4.2^{1+4}_+$. Now the action of $2^{1+4}_+$ on $T_4$ is also explicitly determined.

$\mathbb K$ is algebraically closed with char not equal 2 and P$\Omega_8$($\mathbb K$) is the adjoint algebraic group of type D.

What is the action exactly here? I suppose the four 2 invert the four $T_1$? What about the center? Not sure...

Comment: Is there a connection with $PO_8(\mathbb K)$ ?

Comment: I think it is $PSO_8(K)$

Comment: Attempt a google search with keywords "projective PSO_8" ; you could also crosspost this rather specialized question on MathOverflow.

Comment: What do $T_4$ and $T_1$ denote?

Comment: Thank you for the input. $T_1$ is a one-dimensional torus and $T_4$ is a direct product of 4 copies of $T_1$.